# Multiple version info in windows exe file

Tags: windows, exe

How windows determine default version information to be displayed in property window. I am having trouble with an Exe with 2 version info. On some PC's with Windows 10 it shows always 1st version info and on other PC's with Windows 10 it shows 2nd version info.

There was a mistake done by me to add *.res files during compilation. 
But how windows determine which resource to be used for showing version info in properties.

exe resources list

[image: exe resources list]

Comment: Are those numbers LCIDs?

Comment: I am not sure, but I suppose they are LCIDs.

Comment: Then that explains it. The systems have different language settings.

Answer (score 0):

1030 stands for Danish language. 1033 stands for English US language, in my case version info in both languages was present. so in machines having Danish(DK) Default system UI languages was picking up version info from 1030. And for others it was using version info from 1033.